# Prove $\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{a_k^2 + b_k^2} \ge \sqrt{(\sum a_k )^2 + (\sum b_k)^2}$

Tags: inequality

I know this may be a primary problem but I cannot solve it.
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{a_k^2 + b_k^2} \ge \sqrt{(\sum a_k )^2 + (\sum b_k)^2}$$ with $a_k,b_k$ are positive reals and n is an integer.
I haven't known any inequality that implies a sum of many square roots is greater than something. So basically I was stuck right when I began.

Comment: This says that the sum from $i=1$ to $i=n$ of the (Euclidean) distances (in the plane) from some point $M_{i-1}$ to some other point $M_i$ is always at least the distance from $M_0$ to $M_n$. QED.

Comment: This can be shown intuitively  using the triangle inequality with @Did solution

Comment: @shaihorowitz Not only intuitively. (But why repeat my comment?)

Comment: @Did I didn't think that it was as intuitively clear until the triangle inequality was explicitly mentioned as the reason. you're proof is solid I just wanted to add what I saw as clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably cleverer ways to prove it, but an almost brute force approach works. The inequality is equivalent to the one obtained by squaring both sides:

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{a_k^2+b_k^2}\right)^2\ge\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_k\right)^2+\left(\sum_{k=1}^nb_k\right)^2\;,$$

or, after multiplying out, subtracting $\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2+\sum_{k=1}^nb_k^2$ from both sides, and dividing through by $2$,

$$\sum_{1\le j<k\le n}\sqrt{(a_j^2+b_j^2)(a_k^2+b_k^2)}\ge\sum_{1\le j<k\le n}(a_ja_k+b_jb_k)\;.\tag{1}$$

For each pair $j,k$ such that $1\le j<k\le n$ we have

$$\begin{align*}
(a_j^2+b_j^2)(a_k^2+b_k^2)-(a_ja_k+b_jb_k)^2&=(a_jb_k)^2+(a_kb_j)^2-2a_ja_kb_jb_k\\
&=(a_jb_k-a_kb_j)^2\\
&\ge 0\;,
\end{align*}$$

and $(1)$ follows immediately.